# wubi still said files is missing after disable UEFI

Tags: uefi, ubuntu-12.04

After an installation of Ubuntu with wubi and selecting UEFI and csm 
UEFI is disabled

However, wubi still said `files is missing`.

Do i need to install with wubi again?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/694242

Answer (score 1):

WUBI doesn't work with EFI. You must do a regular install of Ubuntu, not a WUBI install.